# Find smallest list under conditions

Tags: prolog, min, member

In SWI-Prolog I want to establish the list L from two lists **L1** and **L2** with the smallest count of elements under the condition, that `1 ∈ L1` and `1 ∈ L2`.
If `1 ∉ L1` and `1 ∈ L2`, then `L = L1`. If `1 ∈ L1` and `1 ∉ L2`, then `L = L2`. If `1 ∉ L1` and `1 ∉ L2`, then the predicate returns false.

I could evaluate this in Prolog with the following conditions:

```
minset_one(D1, D2, T) :- ((member(1, D1), not(member(1, D2))) -> T=D1).
minset_one(D1, D2, T) :- ((not(member(1, D1)), member(1, D2)) -> T=D2).
minset_one(D1, D2, T) :- (member(1, D1), member(1, D2), length(D1,L1), length(D2,L2), L1 >= L2) -> T=D2.
minset_one(D1, D2, T) :- (member(1, D1), member(1, D2), length(D1,L1), length(D2,L2), L2 > L1) -> T=D1.
```

My problem with that function is, the member function is called very often. Is their a way to reduce the complexity of that predicate in that way, the functions

- `member(1, D1)`
- `member(1, D2)`
- `length(D1, L1)`
- `length(D2, L2)`

are called only one time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your code and the code in [the answer of @TessellatingHacker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71699969/4609915) lose [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity) when the arguments of `minset_one/3` are not sufficiently instantiated:

```
?- D1 = [X,Y,Z], D2 = [U,V], minset_one(D1,D2,T).
   D1 = [1,Y,Z], D2 = [1,V], T = D2
;  false.                           % no more solutions!
```

This is clearly incomplete. There *are* other solutions. We lost [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity).

So, what can we do about this?
Basically, we have two options:

1. check `D1`, `D2` and `T` upfront and throw an `instantiation_error` when the instantiation is not sufficient.
2. use building blocks that are better suited for code that preserves [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity).

---

In this answer I want to show how to realise option number two.

The code is based on [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915) which is the core of [`library(reif)`](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.01590.pdf).
In short, we reify the truth values of relations and use Prolog indexing on these values.

Using SWI-Prolog 8.4.2:

```
?- use_module(library(reif)).
```

First, `shorter_than_t(Xs,Ys,T)`
reifies *"list `Xs` is shorter than `Ys`"* into `T`:

```
shorter_than_t([],Ys,T) :-
   aux_nil_shorter_than(Ys,T).
shorter_than_t([_|Xs],Ys,T) :-
   aux_cons_shorter_than_t(Ys,Xs,T).

aux_nil_shorter_than_t([],false).
aux_nil_shorter_than_t([_|_],true).

aux_cons_shorter_than_t([],_,false).
aux_cons_shorter_than_t([_|Ys],Xs,T) :-
   shorter_than_t(Xs,Ys,T).
```

Based on `shorter_than_t/3` we define `minset_one/3`:

```
minset_one(D1,D2,T) :-
   if_(shorter_than_t(D1,D2),
       if_(memberd_t(1,D1), D1=T, (memberd_t(1,D2,true),D2=T)),
       if_(memberd_t(1,D2), D2=T, (memberd_t(1,D1,true),D1=T))).
```

Now let's run above query again:

```
?- D1 = [X,Y,Z], D2 = [U,V], minset_one(D1,D2,T).
   D1 = [X,Y,Z], D2 = [1,V], T = D2
;  D1 = [X,Y,Z], D2 = [U,1], T = D2, dif(U,1)
;  D1 = [1,Y,Z], D2 = [U,V], T = D1, dif(U,1), dif(V,1)
;  D1 = [X,1,Z], D2 = [U,V], T = D1, dif(U,1), dif(V,1), dif(X,1)
;  D1 = [X,Y,1], D2 = [U,V], T = D1, dif(U,1), dif(V,1), dif(X,1), dif(Y,1)
;  false.
```

At last, `minset_one/3` has become complete!

Comment: Ahh, I did search for 'reification' thinking it might be relevant here, but only found references to clpfd using it. *Why* does my code lose logical purity, when `member(1, [A,B,C])` does backtrack over A=1, B=1, C=1?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler. `member/2` by itself is pure. But using it in `(->)/2` can make it impure, because `(->)/2` eliminates alternative solutions, just like [tag:prolog-cut].

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler. If you are interested in a minimal change to your code that makes it preserve [tag:logical-purity], I suggest posting a new question about that. I'd be glad to answer it:)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do it with a wrapper / helper predicate which does those checks once, and then does a lookup of some fixed answers:

```
% minset_one(1 in D1, 1 in D2, D1, D2, D1Len, D2Len, T).
minset_one_(true,  false, D1, _,  _,     _,     D1).
minset_one_(false, true,  _,  D2, _,     _,     D2).
minset_one_(true,  true,  _,  D2, D1Len, D2Len, D2) :- D1Len >= D2Len.
minset_one_(true,  true,  D1, _,  D1Len, D2Len, D1) :- D1Len < D2Len.

minset_one(D1, D2, T) :-
    (member(1, D1) -> D1check = true ; D1check = false),
    (member(1, D2) -> D2check = true ; D2check = false),
    length(D1, D1Len),
    length(D2, D2Len),
    
    minset_one_(D1check, D2check, D1, D2, D1Len, D2Len, T).
```