# What minimal change to my code would make it preserve logical purity?

Tags: prolog, logical-purity

I posted the code below [as an answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71699969/478656) and [user "repeat" answered and commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71696650/find-smallest-list-under-conditions/71712939?noredirect=1#comment126748805_71712939) that it's not logically pure and "*if you are interested in a minimal change to your code that makes it preserve logical-purity, I suggest posting a new question about that. I'd be glad to answer it :)*".

```
% minset_one(1 in D1, 1 in D2, D1, D2, D1Len, D2Len, T).
minset_one_(true,  false, D1, _,  _,     _,     D1).
minset_one_(false, true,  _,  D2, _,     _,     D2).
minset_one_(true,  true,  _,  D2, D1Len, D2Len, D2) :- D1Len >= D2Len.
minset_one_(true,  true,  D1, _,  D1Len, D2Len, D1) :- D1Len < D2Len.

minset_one(D1, D2, T) :-
    (member(1, D1) -> D1check = true ; D1check = false),
    (member(1, D2) -> D2check = true ; D2check = false),
    length(D1, D1Len),
    length(D2, D2Len),
    
    minset_one_(D1check, D2check, D1, D2, D1Len, D2Len, T).
```

e.g.

```
?- D1 = [X,Y,Z], D2 = [U,V], minset_one(D1,D2,T).

D1 = [1, Y, Z],
D2 = T, T = [1, V],
U = X, X = 1 ;

false
```

there are more solutions possible. `member(1, D1)` is not backtracking through `[1, Y, Z]`, then `[X, 1, Z]` then `[X, Y, 1]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### The Problem with `(->)/2` (and friends)

Consider the following goal:

```
(member(1,D1) -> D1check = true ; D1check = false)
```

`(->)/2` commits to the first answer of `member(1,D1)`—other answers are disregarded.

Can alternatives to `(->)/2`—like `(*->)/2` (SWI, GNU) or `if/3` (SICStus)—help us here?

[No](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33173811/4609915). These *do* not ignore alternative answers to make `member(1,D1)` succeed, but they do not consider that the logical negation of `member(1,D1)` could *also* have succeeded.

#### Back to basics: "If P then Q else R" ≡  "(P ∧ Q) ∨ (¬P ∧ R)"

So let's rewrite `(If -> Then ; Else)` as `(If, Then ; Not_If, Else)`:

```
(member(1,D1), D1check = true ; non_member(1,D1), D1check = false)
```

How should we implement `non_member(X,Xs)`—can we simply write `\+ member(X,Xs)`?

No! To preserve logical purity we better not build upon "negation as finite failure".

Luckily, combining `maplist/2` and `dif/2` does the job here:

```
non_member(X,Xs) :-
   maplist(dif(X),Xs).
```

#### Putting it all together

So here's the minimum change I propose:

```
minset_one_(true,  false, D1, _,  _,     _,     D1).
minset_one_(false, true,  _,  D2, _,     _,     D2).
minset_one_(true,  true,  _,  D2, D1Len, D2Len, D2) :- D1Len >= D2Len.
minset_one_(true,  true,  D1, _,  D1Len, D2Len, D1) :- D1Len < D2Len.

non_member(X,Xs) :- 
   maplist(dif(X),Xs).

minset_one(D1, D2, T) :-
   (member(1,D1), D1check = true ; non_member(1,D1), D1check = false),
   (member(1,D2), D2check = true ; non_member(1,D2), D2check = false),
   length(D1, D1Len),
   length(D2, D2Len),
   minset_one_(D1check, D2check, D1, D2, D1Len, D2Len, T).
```

Running the sample query we now get:

```
?- D1 = [X,Y,Z], D2 = [U,V], minset_one(D1,D2,T).
   D1 = [1,Y,Z], X = U, U = 1, D2 = T, T = [1,V]
;  D1 = [1,Y,Z], X = V, V = 1, D2 = T, T = [U,1]
;  D1 = T, T = [1,Y,Z], X = 1, D2 = [U,V], dif(U,1), dif(V,1)
;  D1 = [X,1,Z], Y = U, U = 1, D2 = T, T = [1,V]
;  D1 = [X,1,Z], Y = V, V = 1, D2 = T, T = [U,1]
;  D1 = T, T = [X,1,Z], Y = 1, D2 = [U,V], dif(U,1), dif(V,1)
;  D1 = [X,Y,1], Z = U, U = 1, D2 = T, T = [1,V]
;  D1 = [X,Y,1], Z = V, V = 1, D2 = T, T = [U,1]
;  D1 = T, T = [X,Y,1], Z = 1, D2 = [U,V], dif(U,1), dif(V,1)
;  D1 = [X,Y,Z], D2 = T, T = [1,V], U = 1, dif(X,1), dif(Y,1), dif(Z,1)
;  D1 = [X,Y,Z], D2 = T, T = [U,1], V = 1, dif(X,1), dif(Y,1), dif(Z,1)
;  false.
```

Better. Sure looks to me like there's nothing missing.

Comment: I see; and I think I understand, thanks :).  (It must traverse the list twice, once for member/2 to fail and once again for non_member to succeed?)

Comment: Yes, going through the list twice is necessary with this approach; `memberd_t/3` reduces that cost, but it does more: if helps keep the number of choicepoints low, while covering the maximally general cases.

Comment: I can sense some interesting questions lurking here, of course: 1 how to show that one pure implementation gives redundant answers for a specific query while another one does not, 2 how to get rid of these redundant answers.

Answer (score 5):

I think it would be:

add:

```
:- use_module(library(reif)).
```

... and replace:

```
    %(member(1, D1) -> D1check = true ; D1check = false),
    %(member(1, D2) -> D2check = true ; D2check = false),
    memberd_t(1, D1, D1check),
    memberd_t(1, D2, D2check),
```

Example of the difference between member and memberd_t:

```
?- member(X, [A, B, C]).
X = A ;
X = B ;
X = C.

?- memberd_t(X, [A, B, C], IsMember).
X = A,
IsMember = true ;
X = B,
IsMember = true,
dif(A,B) ;
X = C,
IsMember = true,
dif(A,C),
dif(B,C) ;
IsMember = false,
dif(A,X),
dif(B,X),
dif(C,X).

?- memberd_t(X, [A, B, C], IsMember), X = 5, A = 5, C = 5.
X = A, A = C, C = 5,
IsMember = true ;
false.
```

So, memberd_t is itself adding the dif/2 constraints. To aid performance slightly, it loops through the list only once.

The definition of memberd_t is at e.g. https://github.com/meditans/reif/blob/master/prolog/reif.pl#L194 and https://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/file_details/reif/prolog/reif.pl?show=src

Comment: Very smart indeed:)

Comment: Thank you; it is an answer, it works, and it answers what I actually asked in that it's a minimal change which makes it logically pure, so upvote.  But if it was "How can I fix my ellipse drawing code so it can draw perfect circles?" I think "Use a drawing library with a circle function" would not be the kind of answer I was desiring. I really wanted to know what's wrong with my attempt at reification using `->` and how could I write just that bit better.

Comment: I have added a bit more explanation. @repeat's explanation is of course better than mine :-)